# Making a MouseAdapter refer to the JComponent it's being added to

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I have a multitude of  Buttons that should mostly function in the same way, but change different variables linked to the button when pressed (mainly the color). I want to slim the code down as much as possible (and not type the same thing 10 times).

How would I go about writing this adapter so it can be used for button1, as well as button2?

```
MouseAdapter customMouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                button1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

            }
        };

    button1.addMouseListener(customMouseAdapter);
    button2.addMouseListener(customMouseAdapter);
```

Comment: See [`EventObject.getSource()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource--). And please consult the Java Docs (or your IDE's pop-up of available methods on objects passed to the listener) before asking on SO in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
public class ColourMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter
{
    private final Color colour;
    private final JButton button;
    public ColourMouseAdapter(JButton button, Color colour)
    {
        this.colour = colour;
        this.button = button;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
         button.setForeground(colour);
    }
}
JButton jbutton = new JButton();
jButton.addMouseListener(new ColourMouseAdapter(jbutton, Color.WHITE));
```

or you can do this like others suggested

```
public class ColourMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter
{
    private final Color colour;
    public ColourMouseAdapter(Color colour)
    {
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
         if(e.getSource() instanceof JButton)
         {
              JButton button = e.getSource();
              button.setForeground(colour);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: (1-) Don't create a listener with the button as a parameter. Read Andrew's comment above. You just get the button that was clicked by using the `getSource()` method of the `MouseListener`.

Comment: Yeah you can do it that way, but technically this method also works as the OP requires. And to why he wants a mouse adapter instead of an ActionListener on a JButton is beyond me.

Comment: @camickr added another class on how to get the JButton from source but both answers are acceptable, achieves the same thing.

Comment: They achieve the same thing but one design is better than the other. When you get the "button" from the source event you only need a single listener that can be shared by 100 buttons. If you use your first suggestion you would need to create 100 different listeners. Not very efficient. Always attempt to create a generic listener so it can be reused by multiple components. If this case you don't event need to check for the component being a JButton. You could change the foreground on any component, if you so desire. Don't restrict the code.